# why is it constant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functional-equations

$f$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to  $\Bbb R$:
$\frac{f(x+y)}{(x+y)} - (x+y)^2 =  \frac{f(x-y)}{(x-y)} - (x-y)^2$ for all $x$ and $y$

the solution book just says "Thus  $\frac{f(x)}{x} - x^2$ is a constant"

how did they conclude that ?

Comment: To write $\Bbb R$, you can use `\Bbb R` or `\mathbb R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=\frac {w+z}2$ and $y=\frac {w-z}2$ we have $x+y=w$ and $x-y=z$ and the functional equation becomes

$$\frac {f(w)}w-w^2=\frac {f(z)}z-z^2$$ But $w$ and $z$ were any (non-zero) numbers we chose, so the expression must be constant (aside from the case of zero).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For any $u,v$ you can write $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$. Why?

Comment: i keep forgetting these algebra tricks , thank you